# User based if statements

Tags: c

I'm trying to print a colour based on a user entered letter but it returns the else statement of "wrong colour!" even if I enter in the correct letter

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char b1r1;
  printf("Please enter a value: ");
  scanf("%c", &b1r1);

  char K;
  char R;

  printf("Your colour is: ");
  if(b1r1 == K)
  {
    printf("black");
  }
  if(b1r1 == R)
  {
    printf("red");
  }
  else {
    printf("wrong colour!");
  }
  return 0;     
}
```

Comment: `K` and `R` are both uninitialized, this is undefined behavior. What would the "correct" letter be?

Comment: It would be either K or R, sorry I'm new to C but how do I initialize a character?

Comment: Don't need variables. Just use literals: `if (b1r1 == 'K')`. If you really want variables for other reasons then: `char K = 'K';`

Comment: `char K` does not create a "K" character; it creates a *variable* named "K" that can store a (1-byte) character.

Answer (score 1):

`K` and `R` are both uninitialized here, the behavior is thus undefined. Also, your second `if` is missing an `else`. You could do

```
char K = 'K';
char R = 'R';

printf("Your colour is: ");
if (b1r1 == K) {
    printf("black");
} else if(b1r1 == R) {
    printf("red");
} else {
    printf("wrong colour!");
}
```

**or** remove the `K` and `R` variables, and do

```
printf("Your colour is: ");
if (b1r1 == 'K') {
    printf("black");
} else if(b1r1 == 'R') {
    printf("red");
} else {
    printf("wrong colour!");
}
```

You currently only recognize capital letters, but you could use the [`toupper(int)`](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/library-function/ctype.h/toupper) function from `ctype.h` and support lower case letters as well. Like

```
printf("Your colour is: ");
if (toupper(b1r1) == 'K') {
    printf("black");
} else if(toupper(b1r1) == 'R') {
    printf("red");
} else {
    printf("wrong colour!");
}
```